# Reflexion Perfect Forwarding and the Visitor Pattern

Tags: c++, c++11

http://codepad.org/etWqYnn3

I'm working on some form of a reflexion system for C++ despite the many who have warned against.  What I'm looking at having is a set of interfaces IScope, IType, IMember, IMonikerClient and a wrapper class which contains the above say CReflexion.  Ignoring all but the member which is the important part here is what I would like to do:

1) Instance the wrapper

2) Determine which type is to be used

3) Instance type

4) Overload the () and [] to access the contained member from outer(the wrapper) in code as easily as it is done when using a std::vector

I find that using 0x I can forward a method call with any type for a parameter.  I can't however cast dynamically as cast doesn't take a variable(unless there are ways I am unaware of!)

I linked the rough idea above.  I am currently using a switch statement to handle the varying interfaces.  I would, and for obvious reasons, like to collapse this.  I get type match errors in the switch cases as a cause of the call to the methods compiling against each case where only one of three work for any condition and compiler errors are thrown.

Could someone suggest anything to me here?  That is aside from sticking to VARIANT :/

Thanks!

Comment: 1. It's "reflection" not "reflexion". 2. You would need to annotate every method/scope/class etc manually to achieve something like reflection. You're running into issues simply because C++ does not expose the kind of information you're looking for. 3. You couldn't think of a better name for your structures than "A" "B" or "C"?

Answer (score 1):

C++, even in "0x land", simply does not expose the kind of information you would need to create something like reflection.

> I find that using 0x I can forward a method call with any type for a parameter.

You cannot forward a type as a parameter. You can forward the const-volatile qualifiers on a member, but that's all done in templates, at compile time. No runtime check ever is done when you're using things like forward.

Your template there for operator() is not going to compile unless `T` is convertable to `int*`, `string*`, and `A**` all at once. Think of templates as a simple find and replace algorithm that generates several functions for you -- the value of T gets replaced with the typename when the template is instantiated, and the function is compiled as normal.

Finally, you can only use `dyanmic_cast` to cast down the class hierarchy -- casting between the completely unrelated types A B and C isn't going to operate correctly.

You're better off taking the time to rethink your design such that it doesn't use reflection at all. It will probably be a better design anyway, considering even in language with reflection, reflection is most often used to paper over poor designs.